# Two motor controllers in parallel

Tags: inverter, motor-controller, automotive, parallel, electric-vehicle

Can I, when connecting two inverters (motor controllers) in parallel, control each current independetly? Also is it possible to charge a battery trough a inverter (motor controller) with both inverter connected to a motor?

[image]

This is the type of motor controller I am talking about. As far as I know when using the vector control the inverter is capable of controlling the iq and the id that it's send to the motor, but after reading some control logics in some manuals for the weg cvw500 and emDrive500, whats is actually eletric determined by the circuit is the voltage. As in parallel the inverters need to be in phase and with the same voltage, my assumption was that they would send the same current, but i needed to control them individually, because one of my inverters would be supplied by a fuel cell that shouldn't be managed as battery with abrupt changes in current.

About the charging part, this controllers are capable of regen braking, that means they can charge the battery, but I dont know if there is a way to flow currente from a inveter to another as if it was a motor recovering energy without exciting the motor or while i am producing more energy than my motor is demanding.